# EntityFramework OwnedType with Soft-delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an issue with Owned Types on my entites, because I added an override for SaveChanges to make soft-deletes possible. Basically I override the state of the Entity to modified instead of delete in the SaveChanges and add some meta information to the entity. This works well unless I add a OwnedType onto the entity.

When I do this, EF tries to set all values from the OwnedType to NULL, which is not possible in my example because the Strings are not nullable.

I am not exactly sure how I can fix this behaviour, because I need to set the DeleteBehaviour to NoAction, but I couldn't find a way to do this at the moment. Can anyone explain to me how I can solve this issue?

**MainEntity.cs**

```
public class MainEntity: SoftDeleteEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public LocalizedStringSet MultilangTitle { get; set; } = new LocalizedStringSet();
}
```

**LocalizedStringSet.cs**

```
public class LocalizedStringSet
{
    [MaxLength(4000)]
    public string En { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [MaxLength(4000)]
    public string Fr { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**MainEntityConfiguration.cs**

```
public class MainEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MainEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MainEntity> builder)
    {
        if (builder is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        }

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.OwnsOne(o => o.MultilangTitle);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    if (entry.Entity is ISoftDeleteEntityBase managedCreationSoftDelete)
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                {
                        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                        managedCreationSoftDelete.DeletedBy = creator;
                        managedCreationSoftDelete.Deleted = DateTime.Now;
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve it, but I am not sure if there is a better way to do this.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    if (entry.Entity is ISoftDeleteEntityBase managedCreationSoftDelete)
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                {
                        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                        managedCreationSoftDelete.DeletedBy = creator;
                        managedCreationSoftDelete.Deleted = DateTime.Now;
                        
                        foreach (var reference in entry.References)
                        {
                            if (reference.TargetEntry?.Entity.GetType() == typeof(LocalizedStringSet))
                            {
                                if (reference.TargetEntry != null)
                                {
                                    reference.TargetEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: A better way is to not use "soft delete". There's no "soft delete" in a business process, there are additional business transactions that reverse, compensate or modify previous ones. "Soft" deletes are a developer trick to handle this without actually following that business process. Besides, if you really want a "soft" delete you code shouldn't be calling `Delete()` in the first place

Comment: If you really want to update instead of delete, you need to use an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` table trigger. Your application is just one of many clients that will modify that database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is definitely not a developer trick and quite a common request from the business side. i.e. being able to delete a reference, while still keeping the information on a related entity. 

And no, the database is used just by one software and uses EF first approach, no table triggers.

Comment: Name a *single* **business** process that asks for this. Not how developers translate the need to version data or track changes. An order is never deleted or marked "inactive". It may be cancelled or fulfilled. A deposit is never deleted, softly or otherwise. Neither is a payment or deposit or flight booking. Trying to mimic cancellations and business transactions through "soft deletes" causes far more headaches down the line. Check [Avoid Soft Deletes](https://ayende.com/blog/4157/avoid-soft-deletes) written by Ayende, at the time the maintainer of NHibernate.

Comment: Even if you don't model the actual business transactions, it's easier to handle auditing needs using a database's change tracking, auditing or temporal table features. In SQL Server you can use temporal tables to track all changes to a table into a History table and still have a table with just the current data. Triggers can be used to copy modified or deleted data to audit or history tables. The same can be done with [EF interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors)

Comment: A bit late to the party, but a compromise could be to not handle the soft delete in the `SaveChanges` method, but instead add an overload to the context `Remove` methods.

That way you would not need to switch states on the entry manually but could just modify your entity as you would in a normal update without any side effects from it having been in the state "deleted".

The downside of course being that you'd have to call the new method in all relevant places.